# Load desktop version of a html page in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I researched a lot but not found anything working, i want my webview to open a desktop version not a mobile version of a html page... what is the way to do that?

this is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jobs);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        jwv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.jobsweb);

        jwv.loadUrl("https://2ce74af0d8de8783b91cdd315eeba0340a4b9277.googledrive.com/host/0B2sDUzNeIK0KODB0ZDRMVjFPaFE/Jobs.html");
        String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
        jwv.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
        jwv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                 Toast.makeText(Jobs.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
             });

        final Activity MyActivity = this;

        jwv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");

                MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if (progress == 100)
                    MyActivity.setTitle("Jobs");
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: When you used a search engine to search for `android webview desktop`, what did you learn?

Comment: try to set user_agent like a desktop browser user agent in your http request ! maybe help you

Comment: @CommonsWare i tried this.... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, since that user agent says "Android", some sites may elect to serve up a mobile edition of a Web page. Try a different user-agent string, one that does not reference a mobile OS or device model (e.g., GT-P7500).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force webview to display desktop sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953717/force-webview-to-display-desktop-sites)

Comment: @y.feizi i also tried with that

Comment: @CommonsWare no, i am new in android world...so i dont know what are the different ways..

Comment: i dont know it is not forcing to open a desktop view

Answer (score 0):

your problem is there :

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.1; en-US; GT-P7500 Build/HMJ37) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Desktop Safari/534.13";
 mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
```

its an android 3.1 user-agent !

Use this user-agent instead:

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
```

Comment: I think the u-a that you choose is wrong ! review it carefuly and try some other user-agent ! i cant help anymore